# How to right-align a column when selecting data?

Tags: mysql, sql

A school assignment I'm working on says to format a decimal(14,0) column "as currency [US$xxx,xxx] and right justified [all the commas line up vertically]."

I can select the data in the correct format using this:

```
CONCAT("US$", FORMAT(theColumn, 0))
```

But the data is not right justified. I've been searching and searching and simply haven't been able to find any way to right justify the output.

I did find an answer on here that shows how to do it if the column is a string type and has a fixed width, but I can't find a way to right justify the output for a decimal data type. Is it possible?

EDIT:

MySQL returns data left justified, like this:

```
US$18,100,000,000
US$130,100,000,000
US$1,200,000,000
```

I want to select it right justified, like this:

```
 US$18,100,000,000
US$130,100,000,000
  US$1,200,000,000
```

Answer (score -10, accepted):

I think the following query is the answer to your question.
Since the maximum length for a DECIMAL(14,0) type as represented with separators is 18 you have to find out how many spaces you need to add in front of every concatenated result. I calculate the number of digits of number, then the number of commas ((length of the number -1) DIV 3) and finally the number of spaces to be added (18 - numberlength - separatorslength).Hope I am not missing something.

```
SELECT column_name,
CONCAT("US$", FORMAT(column_name, 0)) as authorstry,
CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(FORMAT(column_name, 0) AS CHAR(18))) AS stringlength,
CHAR_LENGTH(column_name) as numofdigits, 
((CHAR_LENGTH(column_name)-1) DIV 3) as numofseparators,
(18-(CHAR_LENGTH(column_name))-((CHAR_LENGTH(column_name)-1) DIV 3)) as spacestobeadded
CONCAT(SPACE(18-(CHAR_LENGTH(column_name))-((CHAR_LENGTH(column_name)-1) DIV 3)) ,"US$",FORMAT(column_name, 0)) as finalresutl  
 FROM table;
```

Comment: Oh my lord.. It doesn't work for me, but I'm choosing it as the correct answer anyway. You deserve it!

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, *don't mark it as the answer.*

Comment: @Tom This edit was downright defacing the answer. If you think this answer is not useful or not working, downvote and comment. Defacing is not okay.

Answer (score 25):

I think you want

```
select lpad(column_name,x,' ') from table_name;
```

where x is the number of places you want that value you fill (so say 8 places)

Comment: +1 for trying, but all that does is add spaces at the beginning of each column (it doesn't right justify them).

Comment: Indeed, align to the right is just what we experience visually. From the mysql programm point of view, align to left (what is the default) means complete with `' '` char after output column value. Then align to right is do inverse, complete with these char before the value.

Answer (score 8):

I would have done:

```
LPAD(CONCAT("US$", FORMAT(theColumn, 0)),20,' ')
```

What this does is present the output in a column of 20 characters, padding ' ' to the left of values.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
RIGHT(CONCAT("              US$", theColumn), 17)
```

Basically, prefix your_field with enough spaces to fill your display column, then take the right most characters from that. So if your display column is 17 characters, prefix your_field with (at least) 17 spaces/"US$" then take the right most 17 characters of that string. 17 is the 14,0 plus the 3 characters in "US$".

Nope, I don't like it either, especially in this day and age, but it does work. I suppose DB engines don't have something sophisticated to do this is the philosophy that the DB is the "Model" and not the "View".

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT with div right align.
Example:

```sql
CONCAT("<div style='text-align:right',(FORMAT(theColumn, 0))
```

This is working with MySQL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).